# Не получается получить данные из Бд sqlite3

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

- 

Пишу бота, вывожу кнопки с названием группы из бд, далее мне нужно через бота отправить расписание на выбранную пользователем группу, но выводит ошибку
*<built-in method fetchall of sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000002DCCF615E40>*

```
def print_rasp(message):
        c = message.text
        conn = sqlite3.connect('rasp/rasp.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from Расписание where Группа = ?;", (c,))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = cur.fetchall)
```

Это печать самого расписания, вот код для проверки:

```
a = ['Ис-11', 'Зи-11','ПСО-12','Уд-01']
elif (message.text in a):
                print_rasp(message)
```

После выводу групп проверка списка проходит корректно, но вот вывод расписания нет
Надеюсь на вашу помощь ***=)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не ошибка, это адрес вашего объекта. Вы печатаете адрес объекта вместо вызова функции, не хватает скобок.

```py
def print_rasp(message):
        c = message.text
        conn = sqlite3.connect('rasp/rasp.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from Расписание where Группа = ?;", (c,))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = cur.fetchall()) # нужно вызвать функцию
```